# How to escape a command line for logging?

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh

I want to echo a command that a script is running for debugging purposes.

So, my script has a line that runs a command:

```
negate() {
    echo \( "$1" -negate \)
}
NEGATED_IMAGE="$(negate 'my image.png')"
convert $=NEGATED_IMAGE two.png -composite out.png
```

And I simply copy paste it above after an echo to see what command was run:

```
echo convert $=NEGATED_IMAGE two.png -composite out.png
convert $=NEGATED_IMAGE two.png -composite out.png
```

The log is not as useful as I want. The above logs

```
convert ( my image.png -negate ) two.png -composite out.png
```

Which cannot be copy-pasted into my own command line to run the same command, because the parentheses are not escaped, neither is the space in the `my image.png` argument escaped or quoted.

So, how can my script log a command line it will execute, in such a way that copy-pasting the logged line into my zsh prompt will run the same command?

So the above case should log something like

```
convert \( 'my image.png' -negate \) two.png -composite out.png
```

Because that is the actual command that the script is executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard output of `$(image_one 'input image.png')` becomes the first paramter of `convert`, hence *convert* sees as first parameter the string `( input image.png -negate )`.

When passing arguments to a program, it makes sense to first write a list of the parameters and which parameter position they should end up. From your description, I understand that `convert` is supposed to get the following parameters:

- $1: `(`
- $2: `input image.png`
- $3: `-negate
- $4: ')'

The goal is therefore to create an array of 4 elements, which then can be interpolated into the call of *convert*. Also you want to use an auxiliary function which just receives the second argument and adds the other 3.

Here is one possible approach:

```
image_one() {
  arrname=${1?Array name missing}
  par2=$2 
  eval $arrname'=( "(" $par2 -negate ")" )
}

image_one myarr 'image image.png'
convert "${myarr[@]}" two.png -composite out.png
```

**UPDATE**

The OP now asserted in a comment that his problem is not the construction of the parameter list, but that he wants to print out the convert command to stdout.

To avoid writing the code twice, the solution is again to use an array, but now for all parts of the command. Example:

```
cmd=( '(' 'my image.png' -negate ')' two.png -composite out.png )
# Log the command
echo -E -- ${(q)cmd}
# Run the command
$cmd
```

Of course you can not catch redirections with this approach, since redirections are not part of the command itself. However, your example does not contain any redirection anyway.

Comment: You may have misunderstood my question, my goal is actually just to log that convert command to stdout, in such a way that I can directly copypaste it into my command prompt and run exactly the same convert command that the script ran

Comment: Indeed. As there is nothing in your code which would attempt something like logging, I thought that the problem was about interpolation. I will add something to my answer to cover the logging case.

Comment: @minseong : See my updated solution.

Comment: Why use `printf` here instead of `echo` ?

Comment: @minseong: To avoid nastiness of "echo". For instance, if you parameter would contain `\a`, echo would turn this into a beep. But thinking of it: Doing a `echo -E -- ...` would do as well here. I'll update my answer.